# jQuery - Append a Value to a INPUT, keeping it a Comma Delimited list

Tags: jquery

I have an input like follows:

```
<input type="hidden" id="attachment-uuids" value="">
```

I'd like to be able to append a value to the Input, at different times:

```
$('#attachment-uuids).val('55555');
```

results in:

```
<input type="hidden" id="attachment-uuids" value="55555">
```

But then doing:

```
$('#attachment-uuids).val('66666');
```

results in:

```
<input type="hidden" id="attachment-uuids" value="66666">
```

Where I'd like the following:

```
<input type="hidden" id="attachment-uuids" value="55555, 66666">
```

how can I append values when the value is empty and when the value is not empty  with a comma delimited list?

Thanks

Comment: What if the value is already in the list?

Comment: @Nick good question, that should never happen but if it does I can take care of that on the backend.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
$('#attachment-uuids').val(function(i,val) { 
     return val + (!val ? '' : ', ') + '66666';
});
```

---

**EDIT:** As [@mkoryak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26188/mkoryak) noted, I'm doing an unnecessary negation of `val` in the conditional operator. It could be rewritten without the `!` as:

```
(val ? ', ' : '')
```

Comment: That is a think of beauty. Thanks!

Comment: if we are going to talk about elegant, then it would be better to flip that ternary and get rid of the negation :P

Comment: @mkoryak, I have no idea what you're saying :)

Comment: @mkoryak - Good point. `(val ? ', ' : '')`  would make more sense.

Comment: what if you want to remove one by one the values?

Answer (score 11):

Just add a conditional when you add the value to the field.

```
var cur_val = $('#attachment-uuids').val();
if(cur_val)
  $('#attachment-uuids').val(cur_val + "," + new_val);
else
  $('#attachment-uuids').val(new_val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Append won't work for input.
But you can use:

```
$("#txt1").get(0).value+="+";
```

Answer (score -4):

I believe the `.append()` function is exactly for this purpose. I just tried:

```
$("#attachment-uuids").append(new_val);
```

to append values to a field. This works and "attachment-uuids" is populated with CSVs, as required.