# jQuery add form input to hidden field input value in correct format

Tags: jquery, html

I have a question very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339066/jquery-append-a-value-to-a-input-keeping-it-a-comma-delimited-list) but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have a input like this:

```
<input id="authorities" name="authorities" type="text">
```

And a hidden input like this:

```
<input id="team_authority_emails" name="team[authority_emails]" type="hidden" value="{asvxcvxcvva@gmail.com,test@test.com.au}">
```

jQuery:

```
$('#authorities').bind("keyup", function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('#team_authority_emails').val(val); 
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve is passing the input value from `authorities` to `team_authority_emails` in the correct format while retaining the present values. E.g. If I added a new email tesdadf@adfs.com the value in my hidden field would become `value="{asvxcvxcvva@gmail.com,test@test.com.au,tesdadf@adfs.com}"`.

Comment: you want to keep all the values you entered in  the hidden input?

Comment: FYI `.on()` is preferred to `.bind()`. And you need to look into concatenation with `+`.

Comment: @MertMetin yes I would like to keep al the values already present and add the new one.

Comment: Thanks @j08691 I've changed to `.on` I'm unsure of how to concatenate while maintaining the values already present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an event triggering the action to add the typed email into the hidden field. I'll be using a button here.

On click, if the email is valid, I grab the text on authorities and replace the value of the hidden field with the present values plus the new one.

```js
function isEmail(posibleEmail) {
  //check if email is valid here somehow
  return true;
}

$('#addEmail').on('click', function() {

  var typedEmail = $('#authorities').val();

  if (isEmail(typedEmail)) {

    var presentEmails = $('#team_authority_emails').val().slice(0, -1);

    $('#team_authority_emails').val(presentEmails + ',' + typedEmail + '}');

    $('#out').html($('#team_authority_emails').val()); //just so you can see the result
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="authorities" name="authorities" type="text">

<button id="addEmail">Add e-mail</button>

<input id="team_authority_emails" name="team[authority_emails]" type="hidden" value="{asvxcvxcvva@gmail.com,test@test.com.au}">

<!-- a div so you can see the result -->
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer makes the most sense to me and you reminded me to validate emails as well!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();

$('#authorities').on("keyup", function() {
  delay(function(){
      var arr = [];
      var email = $('#authorities').val();
      arr.push(email);
      $('#team_authority_emails').val(arr);
      console.log(arr);
      $('#authorities').val('');
  }, 1000 );
});
```

I also added delay for the keyup.

Answer (score 0):

One way is as follows:

```
$('#authorities').bind("keyup", function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(e.which == 13 && value != ''){ //And other validations you may want
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('#team_authority_emails').val(function(i,val) {
            return val + (val ? ', ' : '') + value;
        });
        $(this).val('');
        return false;
    }
});
```

EXPLANATION: Wait until the user press enter key, then add the value to the hidden input and reset the input.

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/9h5rwgp3/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use many ways, i just learn [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript), you can further modify to suit your needs

```
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index,string,separator)
{console.log(index,separator,string);
 return this.substr(0, index) + separator + string + "}" +     this.substr(index+string.length);
}

$("#enter").click(function() {
  var inputA = $("#authorities").val();
  var inputB = $("#team_authority_emails").val();
  console.log(inputB.replaceAt((inputB.length-1),inputA, ","));
  $("#team_authority_emails").val(inputB.replaceAt((inputB.length-1),inputA, "," ));
});
```

Please take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7n8NR/455/), see the log for the result. E.g you input test@gmail.com the result will be `{asvxcvxcvva@gmail.com,test@test.com.au,test}`