# Add/Remove comma-separated input values with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ruby-on-rails-5

I can [add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339066/jquery-append-a-value-to-a-input-keeping-it-a-comma-delimited-list) values to an input and [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596089/how-to-remove-specifc-value-from-array-using-jquery) but what I want to achieve looks messy.

I have two images that when clicked, gives me their user id. So when clicked, a hidden input value of 1 is added. When the other image is clicked, same:

```
<input id="selective-avatars" name="avatars[]" type=hidden value="1,2" />
```

If same image is clicked, again, their id is removed (like a `toggleClass` sort of thing). That is the tricky part I face with piecing the two links together.

**Full HTML (example):**

```
<img src="url" id="1" class="avatar" />
<img src="url" id="2" class="avatar" />
# Should this be in the loop also? It's currently not.
<input id="selective-avatars" name="avatars[]" type=hidden />
```

**JS:**

```
$('.avatar').click(function(){
  let {id} = this;
  //let array = $('#selective-avatars').val().split(',');
  $('#selective-avatars').val(function(i, val){
     return [val + (!val ? '' : ',') + id];
  });
  //Removed about 8 lines as nothing works

  //$(this).toggleClass('avatar-circle-display-loop-select')
});
```

I was trying not going the react route as I wanted to use pure jquery in the side project.

All I want is `<input id="selective-avatars" name="avatars[]" type=hidden value="1,2, etc" />` going to the controller.

Comment: @Satpal That would give me `undefined`. What I have works just fine finding the ids.

Comment: @Sylar: The OP's version is perfectly valid and appropriate ES2015 destructuring assignment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, just realized ;)

Comment: Side note: There's an error repeated three times in the question (I've just fixed it), a missing `"` on the `id`: `<input id="selective-avatars name="avatars[]" type=hidden value="1,2" />` If that was copy-and-paste from your code, you might want to double-check the actual code to see if it's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `id` on the `.avatar` elements tells us what values to include in the hidden input. I'd keep a flag on the element and just rebuild the input value every time:

```
$('.avatar').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data("selected", !$this.data("selected")); // Will be `undefined`
                                                     // initially, which is falsy
    var value = $('.avatar')
        .filter(function() {
            return $(this).data("selected");
        })
        .map(function() {
            return this.id;
        })
        .get()
        .join(",");
    $("#selected-avatars").val(value);
});
```

I notice you've used ES2015 and above features, so in ES2015:

```
$('.avatar').click(function() {
    const $this = $(this);
    $this.data("selected", !$this.data("selected")); // Will be `undefined`
                                                     // initially, which is falsy
    const value = Array.from($('.avatar'))
        .filter(elm => $(elm).data("selected"))
        .map(elm => elm.id)
        .join(",");
    $("#selected-avatars").val(value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me just scan through your code to understand what's going on.

Comment: you have no idea how much refactoring I have to do with your few lines of code! Thank you so much!