# How to add remove a set of comma separated values in an input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML

```
<div class="wrap_temi">
    <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
        <li class="list-inline-item">
            <input type="checkbox" value="amici" autocomplete="off">  Amici
        </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item">
            <input type="checkbox" value="bacio" autocomplete="off">  Bacio
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<input name="usp-tags" id="usp-tags" type="text" value="" data-required="true" required="required" maxlength="999999" placeholder="inserisci uno o più tag..." class="usp-input usp-input-tags form-control" autocomplete="off">
```

I need to be able to add/remove tags in the input as per `amici, bacio`

I tried to use `.map()` but I'm not familiar with it or [following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40843412/1018804) but I am not sure how to apply it to my case.

Comment: so you want the checkbox values to be added to the textbox?

Comment: @epascarello yes please and also to be able to remove them, comma separated, remembering we shouldn't end up with a single comma at the last

Comment: so onchange of the checkbox loop over them and append to an array if checked and join()

Comment: @epascarello exactly

Comment: I recommend using [Tagify](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify) for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you're looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {

    var tags = $('input:checkbox:checked')
    .map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get().join(', ');

    $("#usp-tags").val(tags);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap_temi">
    <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
        <li class="list-inline-item">
            <input type="checkbox" value="amici" autocomplete="off">  Amici
        </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item">
            <input type="checkbox" value="bacio" autocomplete="off">  Bacio
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<input name="usp-tags" id="usp-tags" type="text" value="" data-required="true" required="required" maxlength="999999" placeholder="inserisci uno o più tag..." class="usp-input usp-input-tags form-control" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of retrieving the `value` using `map`.

Use `:checked` to get back the selected options:-

```js
$('.wrap_temi [type="checkbox"]').change(function(){

  var tags = $('.wrap_temi [type="checkbox"]:checked')
  .toArray()
  .map(x => x.value)
  .join(', ');
  
  $('#usp-tags').val(tags);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap_temi">
    <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
        <li class="list-inline-item">
            <input type="checkbox" value="amici" autocomplete="off">  Amici
        </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item">
            <input type="checkbox" value="bacio" autocomplete="off">  Bacio
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<input name="usp-tags" id="usp-tags" type="text" value="" data-required="true" required="required" maxlength="999999" placeholder="inserisci uno o più tag..." class="usp-input usp-input-tags form-control" autocomplete="off">
```