# How to append a value to input if empty or add a comma with value using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4339116/1018804) and this is the code have:

ajax receiver:

```
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery("#assigncat").val(function(i,val) { 
        return val + (val ? '' : ', ') + data.cat_id;
      });
```

But I get:

> 230231

```
<input id="assigncat" value="230231">
```

While I should get: `230,231`

```
<input id="assigncat" value="230,231">
```

Comment: what is cat_id?

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda a number

Comment: try using join(', ');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the two return values of the ternary operator mixed up. It should be:

```
return val + (val ? ', ' : '') + data.cat_id;
```

Comment: the guy from this answer actually says we should avoid it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339066/jquery-append-a-value-to-a-input-keeping-it-a-comma-delimited-list/4339116#4339116

Comment: Sorry - got something mixed up.

Comment: @rob.m Fixed it now, any better?

Comment: let me try it now

Comment: it is now deleting the whole value completely and giving undefined

Comment: That shouldn't be happening - it's from the answer.